# How to fetch data from Amazon Athena using API Gateway and AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a total of more than 200 000 records in the form of CSV files. I set up the Glue crawler and uploaded CSV files to the S3 bucket and crawled by glue crawler. I verified the data with the Athena editor.

By the below query, I checked the number of records and it was 68 000. So I have a total of 68 000 records uploaded and I will upload more data later.

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM "Database"."tablename"
```

I want to display those all data in my frontend section so I created one Lambda method and API gateway to fetch data.

I implemented this API gateway in my frontend section and checked the data. The first time, I got 1 000 records and displayed them in the frontend.

After doing some research, I got it as Athena returns 1 000 records in one call and if there is more data it will return records and nextToken.

So I updated my code to check nexttoken is available or not.
If I get nextToken, I send a request again with nexttoken and will collect more data. I create a recursive method and it checks nexttoken on every request.

After implementation, I checked and I got approximately 9 000 records and after 9 000 records I got null in nexttoken.

After a few days, I checked and I got only 2 000 records and then I got null in Nextoken.

Meanwhile, it's not fixed. Sometimes it returns more data by recursive method and sometimes I get few data. But I never get full data by a recursive method.

I don't understand the correct approach to fetch/display all Athena data into my frontend section by API Gateway and AWS Lambda.

Is there any limitation in Athena or API gateway or AWS Lambda?

Comment: What is the user experience when you display 68 000 items?  Is this really what you want?  I don't have an answer why Athena is being inconsistent but I don't think your users will want to wait on a browser for the system to load 68000 things so they can select 2.

Comment: I have pagination in my front end. The first time it displayed 1000 records. I sent requests in the backend again with the next token in the recursive function. It will collect data and add it to the front end. But the problem is after 2 or 3 requests, I get a null next token.

Comment: Give this a try https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/access-amazon-athena-in-your-applications-using-the-websocket-api/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I started my work in the same way. After getting your response. I am sure I am on the correct way.